# How can I solve these lines from logcat ?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have the following lines from LogCat in android studio. My app is working perfectly but I would like to solve these lines. Actually I don't know if it's normal or not. My min sdk is 11, if it has anything to do with that.

```
      03-31 00:26:19.146    4327-4327/package.app I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file.
    03-31 00:26:19.166    4327-4327/package.app I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority , spota verifySig and checkHash pass. priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-N9005_4.4.2_0040
    03-31 00:26:19.166    4327-4327/package.app I/SELinux﹕ selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /data/security/spota/seapp_contexts
    03-31 00:26:19.166    4327-4327/package.app E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> Normal User
    03-31 00:26:19.166    4327-4327/package.app E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> package.app [ userId:0 | appId:10742 ]
    03-31 00:26:19.166    4327-4327/package.app D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
    03-31 00:26:19.246    4327-4327/package.app W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
    03-31 00:26:19.246    4327-4327/package.app I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
    03-31 00:26:19.306    4327-4327/package.app I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
    03-31 00:26:19.306    4327-4327/package.app W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12251: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
    03-31 00:26:19.306    4327-4327/package.app D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
    03-31 00:26:19.306    4327-4327/package.app I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
    03-31 00:26:19.306    4327-4327/package.app W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12257: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
    03-31 00:26:19.306    4327-4327/package.app D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
    03-31 00:26:19.306    4327-4327/package.app I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
    03-31 00:26:19.306    4327-4327/package.app W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9819: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
    03-31 00:26:19.306    4327-4327/package.app D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
    03-31 00:26:19.316    4327-4327/package.app I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
    03-31 00:26:19.316    4327-4327/package.app W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 415: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
    03-31 00:26:19.316    4327-4327/package.app D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    03-31 00:26:19.316    4327-4327/package.app I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
    03-31 00:26:19.316    4327-4327/package.app W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 437: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
    03-31 00:26:19.316    4327-4327/package.app D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    03-31 00:26:19.316    4327-4327/package.app I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
    03-31 00:26:19.316    4327-4327/package.app W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 378: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
    03-31 00:26:19.316    4327-4327/package.app D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    03-31 00:26:19.316    4327-4327/package.app I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
    03-31 00:26:19.316    4327-4327/package.app W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 380: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
    03-31 00:26:19.316    4327-4327/package.app D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    03-31 00:26:19.396    4327-4327/package.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 152K, 35% free 16963K/25928K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
    03-31 00:26:19.436    4327-4327/package.app I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 47.218MB for 27993616-byte allocation
    03-31 00:26:19.556    4327-4327/package.app D/Activityyyyy: : : :﹕ CREATE 111111
    03-31 00:26:19.596    4327-4327/package.app D/Activityyyyy: : : :﹕ START
    03-31 00:26:19.606    4327-4327/package.app D/Activityyyyy: : : :﹕ RESUME
    03-31 00:26:19.616    4327-4327/package.app D/Activityyyyy: : : :﹕ pause
    03-31 00:26:19.656    4327-4327/package.app I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
        OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08+13
        Build Date: 03/28/14 Fri
        Local Branch: 0328_AU200_patches
        Remote Branch:
        Local Patches:
        Reconstruct Branch:
    03-31 00:26:19.706    4327-4327/package.app D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
    03-31 00:26:22.116    4327-4327/package.app D/Activityyyyy: : : :

﹕ RESUME
```

Comment: It looks like the support library is checking to see if higher level functions exist, and then emulating them if not.  I'm not sure if you can fix that, other than by testing on a higher version of Android.  Its not a bug, its expected behavior.

Comment: I've always tested it on my phone, which has KitKat 4.4.2